# Laravel 5.5 \Socialite\Two\InvalidStateException

Tags: laravel-5.5, laravel-socialite

Socialite was working just fine until I updated to Laravel 5.5. I am getting a:

> \Socialite\Two\InvalidStateException

The Whoops page error on line 209 from `/Users/marcellopato/Sites/cepcar/vendor/laravel/socialite/src/Two/AbstractProvider.php`:

```
if ($this->hasInvalidState()) {
    throw new InvalidStateException;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this, I'm using Laravel 5.5:

```
return Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/socialite#stateless-authentication